# Looking for a book which tries to speak about the ultimate foundation

Tags: metaphysics, reference-request

I'm interested in philosophically digging as deep as possible. I'm looking for a book whose subject is to speak about the ultimate foundation. I apologise for this scarce description, the topic I'm interested in seems almost indescribable. The only sign of such a book that I can think of would be that things get *really weird* at the foundation. For example: I once had an idea to write a book whose syntax would be self-explanatory, as to avoid the meta-language regress, but I have no idea how to do it.

Using symbolic logic in philosophy is close to my heart, but that's not a necessary requirement for the book I'm looking for.

Thank you for your suggestions, God bless.

Comment: Frege, Husserl and Derrida might be a line of research that’s possibly relevant? Although I thought of Deleuze’s early monograph *What is Grounding?* also

Comment: Wittgenstein's Tractatus Logico Philosophicus, and I'd agree with @JosephWeissman suggestion of Husserl. Internal Time-Consciousness, Analyses Concerning Passive Synthesis, and Experience and Judgment go about as deep as it's possible to go. Husserl's more widely read works (Ideas I, Crisis) are all programmatic, but the three I mentioned is where he actually begins carrying out the program in detail.

Comment: How about the Book of Genesis? *In the beginning God created the heavens and the earth. 2 Now the earth was formless and empty, darkness was over the surface of the deep, and the Spirit of God was hovering over the waters.

3 And God said, “Let there be light,” and there was light. 4 God saw that the light was good, and he separated the light from the darkness. 5 God called the light “day,” and the darkness he called “night.” And there was evening, and there was morning—the first day.* Can't get much more foundational than that.

Comment: @user4894 Oh, I already know that, but I can never hope to fully understand it. ;)